# Some screenshots are not stored in html report

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can save a screenshot to specified folder;however when building HTML Report it. does not save some of the screenshots when using directory path. Here is some of code:

```
    if "Users/Therapists" in name:
            print "Hello type: Link in Users / Therapists"
            xpath_expression = "//*[contains(text(), 'Setup')]/parent::a"
            elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_expression)
            if elems:
                hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elems[0])
                hover.perform()
                time.sleep(5)
                print "Hello Link User/Therapist before the elems loop taking screenshot here"
                driver.save_screenshot('C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/QA/Auto/Temp/xxxxx/screenshots/file_2.png')
                driver.save_screenshot(test_dir_path + name + "-pass.png")
                xpath_expression = "//*[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]/parent::a"
                elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_expression)
                print "Hello Link User/Therapist before the elems loop"
                if elems:
                    for elm in elems:
                        print "Hello Link User/Therapist in the elems loop"
                        #driver.save_screenshot(test_dir_path + name + "-beforeclick-pass.png")
                        #time.sleep(5)
                        elm.click()
                        time.sleep(5)
                        driver.save_screenshot(test_dir_path + name + "-pass.png")
                        driver.save_screenshot('C:/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Documents/QA/Auto/Temp/xxxxxx/screenshots/file_3.png')
                        results_d[name]["status"] = "success"

                        results_d[name]["screenshot"] = test_dir_path + name + "-pass.png"

                        return results_d
```

def build_html_report(results_d, report_number):

```
destination_folder_root = "reports/" + str(report_number) + ""
os.mkdir(destination_folder_root)

js_source = "report_template/js"
css_source = "report_template/css"
screenshot_Source = "screenshots/" + str(report_number)

destination_folder_css = destination_folder_root + "/css"
destination_folder_js = destination_folder_root + "/js"
destination_folder_images = destination_folder_root + "/screenshots/" + str(report_number)
```

Comment: Which screenshots aren't being saved -- the first two near the top of the code, or the last two near the end?  Do you get an error message when it attempts to save them, or do the screenshots just never appear?

Comment: All screenshots are being saved except the one for the code script shown. I was able to capture a screenshot in the specific folder with no issues;however when report get generated it passes the test case but no screenshot is stored in the report.